# Django application w/ middleware to create links using a glossary?

Tags: django

I'm looking for an application using a middleware that would automatically add a link to the definition of a term.

Something like on this page : http://www.jeuxvideo.com/articles/0001/00014721-portal-2-test.htm (terms 'spoiler', 'features', 'level design', etc).

Or has someone done a middleware that could help me doing such an application?

Comment: these aren't links the text is wrapped in a `<span>`, i think it could be done with a custom template tag that parses the text, tests it against a glossary table wraps it in a span and 'reprints' it. something like `{% glossarised context %}`. then use [js](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/js/lexique.js) to create the popup.

Comment: Thanks. I also considered using a template tag or a filter to do so. A filter could be an excellent solution. But a middleware would be more convenient.

Comment: The main problem I see here is that we need an efficient html parser that would put an ``<a href>`` or a ``<span>`` only around text.  This can be achieved using python HTMLParser or ElementTree, but I fear this could imply performance issues.

Comment: hmm not sure about performance but i don't think you'd need htmlparser unless its a hard-coded page. lets say you can make a list of the words that are in your glossary, you could then use regex like `re.compile(r'(%s)' % '|'.join(glossary_words)).sub(r'<span class="">\1</span>')` if wherever the text is coming from is already html you'd probably need to ignore tags. just a thought

Comment: That's exactly the problem: the text is already html (using the awesome ckeditor btw). So it requires something more complex than a simple regexp. I just made a few tests using HTMLParser, and it works just perfectly as expected. And no performance issue, even with a page of 4MB.

Now I'm starting an application to do so. It will be open-source, of course :)
I will send a link here when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having found no solution, I decided to build my own: [django-terms](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-terms), using HTMLParser.

It works but it is a bit “too powerful” for now.

**EDIT:** Since version 0.2, django-terms became quite safe to use.  So don't hesitate and give it a try ;o)

Cheers,

Bertrand